# Using constructors of monobehaviors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, readonly

OK, I know why we don't use constructors on monobehaviors in Unity. For nearly all of the use cases, Start and Awake fit perfectly. Usually.

However, there's a great C# feature that only can be used with constructors — readonly fields. In my particular situation, I work on a project with a lot of developers and write an abstract MonoBehavior that will be subclassed and rewritten a lot of times by a lot of different people. And I want a field to act like constant throughout object's lifetime (or it WILL introduce strange, hard-detectable bugs) but with different values in different subclasses — in other words, a classic use-case for a readonly field. (I don't want to use properties because they have no language-enforce obligation of staying the same.)

So — can I safely use MonoBehavior's constructors? Won't some strange dragon come out of the lair somewhere down the road? What should I know if I choose to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main reasons Unity wants you to stay away from using the constructor is that the constructor isn't called on the main thread, and the constructor is called before serialized data is restored to the object.

So if the readonly fields you're setting in the constructor depend on data from serialized fields, then they won't work right. And if they don't then you can just assign them at initialization.

You could also use a container object to keep your readonly values, but there's nothing stopping someone else from re-assigning that container later.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ReadOnlyTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public string part1 = "alpha";  // change these values in the editor and 
    public string part2 = "beta";  // see the output of the readonly variable "combined"

    public readonly string combined;

    // just assign to readonly vars.
    public readonly string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public readonly float readOnlyFloat = 2.0f;


    public class ReadOnlyContainer {
        public readonly int readOnlyInt;
        public readonly float readOnlyFloat;
        public readonly string readOnlyString;

        public ReadOnlyContainer(int _int, float _flt, string _str) {
            readOnlyInt = _int;
            readOnlyFloat = _flt;
            readOnlyString = _str;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("int:{0} float:{1} string:{2}", readOnlyInt, readOnlyFloat, readOnlyString);
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlyTest() {
        combined = part1 + part2;
    }

    public ReadOnlyContainer container;

    void Awake() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new ReadOnlyContainer(Random.Range(-100,100), Time.realtimeSinceStartup, System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
    }

    void Start () {
        Debug.Log(container.ToString());

        Debug.Log("combine1: " + combined);

        Debug.Log("guid: " + guid);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many unity classes are created by reflection, and there's no way for unity to non-default constructors properly; hence the limitation.

@Calvin's answer points out one very good option:  create classes that are not derived from MonoBehaviour; these can have constructors like any other C#.  You can put those classes into fields in MonoBehaviours as long as your code can tolerate missing instances. If you use the typical quasi-singleton pattern from @Calvin's answer you'll always get an instance when you need one, and you can push the 'give me an instance the first time' logic into a method that can be overridden in derived classes to customize behavior.

If you want constant-like behavior, with the option of different values in derived classes it may be easier to define a method rather than a field. The method is effectively read-only, and it has more predictable mutations as per @Jerdak's answer.

If you must have constructors, the last option is to use the monobehavior as a minimal placeholder and write all of the interesting stuff in a class of your own, then delegate all of the work in the Monobehavior to your class.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OuterPlaceholder: MonoBehaviour {

      public InnerBehavior _Inner;
      public void Awake() {
           if (_Inner == null) {
           _Inner= new InnerBehavior(4);
        }
    }

     public void Update()
     { 
        _Inner.DoUpdate(this);
     }

}

public class InnerBehavior 
{
     public readonly int UpConstant;
     public InnerBehavior (int up)
     {
     UpConstant = up;
     }

     public void DoUpdate(MonoBehaviour owner)
     {
      owner.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * UpConstant * Time.deltaTime);
     }

}
```

This option may work best if you are sure you're going to get a lot of complex inheritance as the project evolves.

Finally: It's perfectly OK to name the field _ReadOnlyField or _DoNotWrite or whatever to tell users not to muck with it. All Python programmers live with the possibility of somebody doing far worse things and it seems to work out fine most of the time :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [script refs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html):

> If you attempt to define a constructor for a script component, it will
>   interfere with the normal operation of Unity and can cause major
>   problems with the project.

MonoBehaviours are constructed many times during serialization, something Unity does quite frequently in the editor and I suspect there is a lot more going on the hood to hook the C layer to C#.  Ultimately the behavior is undefined so it's best not to try.

Regarding "but with different values in different subclasses", [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration [readonly] can only occur as part of the  declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

So no modification in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread, but for what it's worth, it **is** possible to do what you want to achieve, with a little workaround:

```cs
public abstract class TestBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected int myPreciousValue => _myPreciousValue; // or public
  
    private int _myPreciousValue; // your readonly value

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        _myPreciousValue = 2; // assign the value here
    }
}
```